# Did Thanos think of the aftermath of snapping the Infinity Gauntlet?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

According to the [MCU Wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos):

> Thanos is the genocidal warlord from Titan, whose own main objective
>   was to bring stability to the universe, as he believed its massive
>   population would inevitably use up the universe's entire supply of
>   resources and condemn it.

He costed everything for this noble cause. However, he's intelligent enough to know that the universe will become imbalanced again with the population explosion. Did he think of this scenario and gave duty of snapping gauntlet every "X" years to some eternal being?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## He trusted them to solve the problem.

According to some of the directors, Thanos believed that humans would realize their mistake.

> “People have asked us why Thanos didn’t just use the stones to double
>   the resources in the universe, and clearly he is not interested,”
>   Anthony Russo said during the commentary.
>
> “No, it’s about free will,” McFeely added. “That doesn’t solve the
>   problem. We’re just going to get there millions of years from now.
>   This is an opportunity for people to get it right. He trusts them, you
>   know?”
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[‘Avengers: Infinity War’ Directors Explain Why Thanos Didn’t Double the Universe’s Resources - TheWrap](https://www.thewrap.com/infinity-war-directors-explain-thanos-double-universe-resources/)</sub>

So, it seems that the intended output of Genocide was a blank slate for humans.

Comment: *All beings, not just humans 'd realize